# unable to move text up to match boxicon bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have the code below:

```
<div class="vertical-nav" id="sidebar">
            <div class=" px-3 mb-4">
            <div class="media d-flex">
                <div class="media-body">
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav flex-column align-items-start mb-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white font-italic">
                <i class="navbar-icon">
                    <box-icon name='upload' color='#ffffff' size="md"></box-icon>
                </i>
                <i class="fa fa-th-large text-primary fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="navbar-text" >upload</span>
                
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white font-italic">
                    <i class="navbar-icon">
                        <box-icon name='file-blank' color='#ffffff' size="md"></box-icon>
                    </i>
                    <i class="fa fa-th-large text-primary fa-fw"></i>
                    <span class="navbar-text">manage</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Ignore the unclosed divs just a code sample. The code works fine in theory but I am unable to get the text for each navbar item aligned with the icon. I tried using margin-bottom on navbar-text but it did not have any effect (neither did padding). I tried moving the icon down with margin-top and that had no effect.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Flex on the `a` item inside the `li` item. For example:

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css';
  
li a{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.text-primary {
  margin-right:10px;
  font-size:50px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="vertical-nav" id="sidebar">
    <div class=" px-3 mb-4">
      <div class="media d-flex">
        <div class="media-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav flex-column align-items-start mb-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white font-italic">
          <i class="navbar-icon">
            <box-icon name='upload' color='#ffffff' size="md"></box-icon>
          </i>
          <i class="fa fa-th-large text-primary fa-fw"></i>
          <span class="navbar-text" >upload</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white font-italic">
          <i class="navbar-icon">
            <box-icon name='file-blank' color='#ffffff' size="md"></box-icon>
          </i>
          <i class="fa fa-th-large text-primary fa-fw"></i>
          <span class="navbar-text">manage</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=
    , initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .navbar ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        
      }

      .navbar ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
        cursor: pointer;

      }
    </style>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>Home</li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>Search</li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>menu</li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>message</li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>logout</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```